# How to mark a test as xfail (expected failure)?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a Testcafe test that looks for a link and clicks on it. Depending on the environment that I run it in, it may or may not be a valid link, and that is okay. What matters is that the link is found and clicked on, not that it goes to a valid page. For example, it may go to a domain that does not exist.

How can I ignore the error resulting from the click() call? I tried suppressing it in a try/catch, but it did not work.

Another alternative, how can I mark the testcase as XFAIL, so that it will be treated as an expected failure?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, TestCafe does not have built-in tools to suppress this error or treat a test as an expected failure. The only way to suppress the error on clicking on an invalid link is to use try/catch.

However, if your only goal is to find the link on a page, you can use [Selector.exists](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/exists.html) to verify that the selected element exists.

Answer (score 1):

Before clicking on a link you can check whether link exists and it is visible like
`await selector.exists && await selector.with({ timeout: 5000}).visible`